# How to design animations across different screen sizes in Android

Tags: android, animation, screen-size

This is a question about duration of animations, from a UI design perspective.

For example: say I have a box one inch square and I want to make it travel from left to right edges on the screen.
Using dp, I can make sure it's an inch wide. This means the time it takes to cross the screen depends on the physical size of the device. Eg. on a 10" wide device nearly 3 times longer than a 4" wide one.

If I use a standard way of doing animations, I could supply a duration in milliseconds, let's say 300ms. The visual speed of the box on the 4" screen is about 90ms per inch, but on the 10" screen, it'll move 3 times that speed. To the user, that could be a super fast motion. 
Or, instead of specifying the duration across all devices, make it depend on the size, for 10", say 900ms. That makes the box travel at about the same speed but it now takes 3 times longer to cross the available space.
It's easy enough to specify constant values in buckets by dp, say values-w600dp/ perhaps 300ms, values-w1800dp/ perhaps 900ms.

But what do others do, any experienced animators out there... what do you do? In the above example of 4" across versus 10":

1. keep the duration the same so that the box travels 3 times faster to cross the screen
2. move the box at the same speed so that it takes 3 times longer to cross
3. some combination where it goes a bit faster the bigger the screen gets, but modulate it so it doesn't take forever on a really big device... imagine the one inch box travelling across a 48" tv screen!

I guess I'd hope the answer is c), but that would involve some maths to somehow determine an optimal speed?

I'd appreciate advice/experience on this!
thanks